# Safest Sister of Eve Level 4 Security Missions

Tags: eve-online

I'm doing Level 4 SoE for now. I got ganked in Langisi. Moved to Apanake and it seems to be a nice place. I'm thinking about moving to Osmon because it's near Jita. Which system is the safest for L4 SoE missions? Langisi, Apanake, or Osmon?

I'm using a Rattlesnake with 1.5 Bils fit. Not really blingy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To strictly answer the question you asked, Osmon is sec0.7 compared to Lanngisi and Apanake which are sec0.5, meaning the concord response times are "roughly 10" resp. "19 seconds" according to [this page on wiki.eveuniversity](https://wiki.eveuniversity.org/CONCORD#CONCORD_Response_Times). If you can use this to your advantage and can confidently build a gank-proof rattlesnake, go there.

On the other hand, if you were to look on dotlan maps or the in-game galaxy map statistics overview by pod/player kills you'd see that (at the time of writing this answer as an example) Osmon might be the least safe system due to 4x as much traffic and 4 pod kills as opposed to none in Apanake but this does not account for faction warfare, people bullying miners, and what ever other business someone might think is a good idea to conduct.

It is also wise to look into mobile depots and figuring out how quickly you can refit yourself to maximum warp stabilizers should you get unwelcome guests (in which case the general advice is "don't shoot at yellow skulls").

All in all, the safest place to grind missions is the least convenient, your safety is ultimately an illusion, and you should always make sure that either you or someone in your crew can see a big enough picture such as map statistics (whether people are ganking missioneers), purpose of traffic and attention to local (so you can tell passers by and benign locals apart from everyone else), interceptors on d-scan, and generally just being able to gauge what business people have in your part of the galaxy.

**tl;dr:**
There are 3 "safe" systems, as in actually in hi-sec.

- Osmon is closest to jita so that one's obviously targeted by gankers.
- Lanngisi is furthest from jita (22 jumps), meaning it's the least
  convenient place to gank mission runners, meaning sadly that's where
  you're expected to go so that's where I'd look for an easy target.
- This leaves Apanake and it's accessible next-door industry hub which would probably attract more clueless targets.

I would advice Apanake simply because it has worked so well for me before but as always maybe I was just lucky.